# Extract a value following conditions

Tags: r, extract

I have this following example dataset with two variables (Ip and Ge) that could contains one, two (or more) values separated by ";". Each value in Ip is associated to the value of Ge following their order (ex: line3: Abri is associated with Ibr, and Echo is associated with Tyh)

```
Data_test= data.frame(Ip=c("Abri", "Abri", "Abri;Echo", "Echo", "Abri;Abri", "Echo;Abri", "Abri", "Abri;Abri;Echo", "Abri;Abri"), 
           Ge=c("Aju", "Jlt", "Ibr;Tyh", "Rtj", "Ekm;Bty", "Itz;Orv", "Adr", "Dhu;Vfr;Lnh", "Tde;Ijp"), 
           Ca=c(2,13,4,2, 4, 6, 13, 13, 4), Mp=c(5,5,4,3,10,1,17, 15, 2))

Data_test

              Ip          Ge Ca Mp
1           Abri         Aju  2  5
2           Abri         Jlt 13  5
3      Abri;Echo     Ibr;Tyh  4  4
4           Echo         Rtj  2  3
5      Abri;Abri     Ekm;Bty  4 10
6      Echo;Abri     Itz;Orv  6  1
7           Abri         Adr 13 17
8 Abri;Abri;Echo Dhu;Vfr;Lnh 13 15
9      Abri;Abri     Tde;Ijp  4  2
```

I would like to extract in another variable, the values in Ge depending on the value in Ip, Ca and Mp following these rules:

-> (1) Extract all values associated with Echo
-> (2) Extract all values associated with Abri and (with Ca>9 and/or Mp>8)

The output would be

```
> Output_test
              Ip          Ge Ca Mp     Outpout
1           Abri         Aju  2  5        <NA>
2           Abri         Jlt 13  5         Jlt
3      Abri;Echo     Ibr;Tyh  4  4         Tyh
4           Echo         Rtj  2  3         Rtj
5      Abri;Abri     Ekm;Bty  4 10     Ekm;Bty
6      Echo;Abri     Itz;Orv  6  1         Itz
7           Abri         Adr 13 17         Adr
8 Abri;Abri;Echo Dhu;Vfr;Lnh 13 15 Dhu;Vfr;Lnh
9      Abri;Abri     Tde;Ijp  4  2        <NA>
```

I tried to do that using mutate and ifelse, but I dont know how to deal with the case when Ip and Ge contain more than one values. Any help will be appreciated

```
library(tidyverse)

Data_test %>% 
  mutate(Output=ifelse(Ip=="Echo", Ge, 
                       ifelse(Ip=="Abri" & (Ca>9 | Mp>8), Ge, 
                       ifelse( , , ))))
```

Comment: I noticed in the rules you stated, you check for Echo first, but in the actual example, the row `Abri;Abri;Echo Dhu;Vfr;Lnh 13 15 Dhu;Vfr;Lnh` has the Abri ones first. Just wondering if it was a typo of some kind? Or am I misunderstanding it? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for anwsering. Actually, there is no order to check the rules. I just want that the two rules are respected. Then it is better for me to extract the values in the same order that they appear in the Ge variable, but this is not so important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`pmap()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/pmap.html):

Steps:

1. Split Ip and Ge on colons, turning them into the list columns `i` and `g`
2. use pmap() to loop through each row, getting the 'Echo' values, then the 'Abri' values, and collapsing them back into a character vector. For some reason, I get ""s instead of NAs for ones which don't match, so I need to turn ""s into NAs using an `ifelse()`
3. Drop `i` and `g`

```
library(tidyverse)

Data_test |> 
  mutate(i = strsplit(Ip, ";"),
         g = strsplit(Ge, ";"),
         Output = pmap_chr(list(i, g, Ca, Mp), \(i, g, a, m) g[i == "Echo" | (i == "Abri" & (a > 9 | m > 8))] %>% paste(collapse = ";") %>% {ifelse(. == "", NA, .)})) |>
  select(-i, -g)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 5
  Ip             Ge             Ca    Mp Output     
  <chr>          <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      
1 Abri           Aju             2     5 NA         
2 Abri           Jlt            13     5 Jlt        
3 Abri;Echo      Ibr;Tyh         4     4 Tyh        
4 Echo           Rtj             2     3 Rtj        
5 Abri;Abri      Ekm;Bty         4    10 Ekm;Bty    
6 Echo;Abri      Itz;Orv         6     1 Itz        
7 Abri           Adr            13    17 Adr        
8 Abri;Abri;Echo Dhu;Vfr;Lnh    13    15 Dhu;Vfr;Lnh
9 Abri;Abri      Tde;Ijp         4     2 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We can split the `Ip`, `Ge` columns in separate rows splitting on `";"`. I think it would be easier to do processing if we have data in tidy format. We also create a `row` column that keeps track of original row number before splitting.

Using `case_when` apply the conditions and bring all the values together in one column for each `row`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Data_test %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  separate_longer_delim(c(Ip, Ge), ";") %>%
  mutate(Output = case_when(
    Ip == "Echo" ~ Ge, 
    Ip == "Abri" & (Ca > 9 | Mp >8) ~ Ge, 
    .default = NA_character_
  )) %>%
  summarise(across(c(Ip, Ge, Output), ~paste0(na.omit(.), collapse = ";")), 
            across(c(Ca, Mp), first),
            Output = na_if(Output, ""),
            .by = "row") %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  relocate(Output, .after = last_col())

#.             Ip          Ge Ca Mp      Output
#1           Abri         Aju  2  5        <NA>
#2           Abri         Jlt 13  5         Jlt
#3      Abri;Echo     Ibr;Tyh  4  4         Tyh
#4           Echo         Rtj  2  3         Rtj
#5      Abri;Abri     Ekm;Bty  4 10     Ekm;Bty
#6      Echo;Abri     Itz;Orv  6  1         Itz
#7           Abri         Adr 13 17         Adr
#8 Abri;Abri;Echo Dhu;Vfr;Lnh 13 15 Dhu;Vfr;Lnh
#9      Abri;Abri     Tde;Ijp  4  2        <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I did not know the separate_longer_delim function. It is good to know it. I will study that.

Comment: @PatrickParts it's a replacement for `separate_rows()`, if you know that

Answer (score 1):

With a pivot operation in 2 sides you could solve your pb:

```r
Data_test |> 
    separate(col = Ip, sep =";", into = paste0("Ip_", 1:3), fill = "right") |> 
    separate(col = Ge, sep =";", into = paste0("Ge_", 1:3), fill = "right") |> 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Ge"), names_to = "Ge", values_to = "val_Ge") |> 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Ip"), names_to = "Ip", values_to = "val_Ip") |> 
    filter(substr(Ge, 4, 6) == substr(Ip, 4, 6)) |> 
    mutate(
        nb = substr(Ge, 4, 6), 
        output = case_when(
            is.na(val_Ip) | is.na(val_Ge) ~ NA_character_, 
            val_Ip == "Echo" ~ val_Ge, 
            (Ca > 9 | Mp > 8) & val_Ip == "Abri" ~ val_Ge, 
            TRUE ~ NA_character_
        )) |> 
    select(-Ip, -Ge) |> 
    pivot_wider(names_from = "nb", values_from = c("val_Ge", "val_Ip", "output")) |> 
    unite(col = "Ip", starts_with("val_Ip"), sep = ";", na.rm = TRUE) |> 
    unite(col = "Ge", starts_with("val_Ge"), sep = ";", na.rm = TRUE) |> 
    unite(col = "Output", starts_with("output"), sep = ";", na.rm = TRUE) |> 
    select(Ip, Ge, Ca, Mp, Output)
```

It's a bit gross but there may be a way to improve.

Comment: Thank you for you solution, I will study that.